# Autosize text in homescreen widget with support library

Tags: java, android, textview, android-appwidget

I am not able to use support library 26 `app:autoSizeTextType` attribute on textview it forces me to use `AppCompatTextView` class.Regular TextView doesn't recognize `app` prefix like official [docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/autosizing-textview.html).  When i  use AppCompatTextView on widget it brings rendering issuses.Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your parent layout then you can use `app`

Comment: I already did that it says unexpected prefix app found for tag TextView

Comment: have you added support v4 dependency ?

Comment: I tried `com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0` and `com.google.android:support-v4:r7` no changes

Comment: try this one https://github.com/1priyank1/AutosizingTextViews-Demo

Comment: it uses android prefix and not supporting earlier versions

Comment: Hi @CevherKavan  have you resolved this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I just use android prefix for supported versions

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with Android's linter. Try using the `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"` attribute.

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="13sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
```

EDIT: Android has an official response into using AppCompat Views in a RemoteViews way (hint: don') https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37071559